# How to make my app remember the recipient and the app that called it?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I'm sharing images in my application.

Thanks to this code:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I can open my application from Whatsapp Attachment screen.
The problem is that the whole application is opened. when I choose the image, the application gives me the option to share in different other applications. 
I would like my application to remember that I called from whatsapp and who is the recipient( who was chatting with me when I opened). 
Is that possible?

Sorry for my English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't understand, aren't you supposed to simply use `setResult` and `finish` your activity instead of trying to open whatsapp again?

Answer (score 0):

The Intent just match the Intent-filter by comparing their component(if you set)/action/category/type/data  values.
so,If you want the app just select your wanted one,just set the component/class like this:

```
setClass(xxActivity.this,xxActivity.class);
```

in this way,it will start a certain Activity. the action/category/type/data will be ignored.

However,the solution above will work well under the precondition of knowing the Activity detail.And you don't know the `whatsapp`'s detail.

That's to say,you can't make this intent received only by whatsapp.